# How to Create files in Shopify theme Without Using Asset API?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-app-extension

Currently I'm using the Asset API to Create files in the Shopify theme on app installation through the Asset API. What is the alternate way to do the same.

```html
async function createTemplate(requestPayload, mainThemeId) {
  const url = `https://${shopifyStoreUrl}/admin/api/2022-04/themes/${mainThemeId}/assets.json`;
  console.log("Main Theme id is =========================== :", mainThemeId);
  const accessToken = shopifyAdminAPIAccessToken;

  try {
    const response = await axios.put(url, requestPayload, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Shopify-Access-Token': accessToken,
      },
    });
    console.log('create Tempalte Result:', response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('An error occurred at createTemplate:', error.message);
  }
}
```